# Adding TextView object dynamically to a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, dynamic, textview

I have been able to work with TextView elements in a Fragment when they are statically defined in my XML. But when I try to create them dynamically/programatically, I don't see anything displayed. I've created a simple example of the problem I'm having.

This one works, I see the screen updated.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_world, container, false);  
        TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv.setText("Fragment #" + mNum);
        tv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.gallery_thumb));
        return v;
    }
```

This one doesn't work. The XML file diagtextvertical.xml is simply this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
</LinearLayout>
```

The code is as follows.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
       //good View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.diaglist, container, false);   
       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.diagverticaltext, container, false);  
       mycontainer = container;

       LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.diagverticaltext, container, false);
       TextView tv = new TextView(container.getContext());
       tv.setText("Testing...");
       l.addView(tv);
       tv = new TextView(container.getContext());
       tv.setText("Testing1...");
       l.addView(tv);
       tv = new TextView(container.getContext());
       tv.setText("Testing2...");
       l.addView(tv);
        return v;
}
```

I have tried using getActivity() in place of container.getContext(), but no luck. There is something I'm not clear on on how to map the layout to the actual view instance - something different than doing this in an Activity.

There is a second part to my question. My actual goal is to update the view asyncronously based on polled data, so one question I have is how to get my hands on the ViewGroup and the inflater when I'm calling in on my own callback.

Comment: I have resolved this by defining a <ScrollView element as a wrapper around the TableLayout in my XML. This wasn't necessary when I did this same thing in an Activity class. I'm still interested in any insight into this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to android development, but i think you should return `l` instead of `v` in your onCreateView or you should add TextViews to `v`.